# Make Stadia controller work wtih Ubuntu via USB

Tags: drivers, usb, google-chrome, games, steam

Don't get me wrong, the Stadia **controller works with Ubuntu**, but **only through Chrome** and with stadia games, while I have a bunch of **itch.io games**, that are actual folders in my Home with their .bin and .appimage **executables**. It would be great to have the controller work with them as well.

I **tried** to plug in the **controller on my laptop with Windows and Steam** games, and Windows had a bizarre behavior: It recognizes the controller, as a Stadia controller, and Steam recognizes it as Xbox controller, but **the games themselves don't** recognize the controller.

So since my ideal scenario would be having the controller work with my .bin and .appimage games on Ubuntu, how could I do? When I use it on chrome the controller has to be **plugged in via USB**, so there must be some inputs that the machine is receiving and only Chrome can read.
Some details about my Desktop:

```
~$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 0d)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series) (rev 02)

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)

00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0)

00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a308 (rev 10)

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

03:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT8893E PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 41)

05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

By the way, I've never been into the idea of subscribing to Stadia, but they sent me the controller at home for free since I'm a YT premium member.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can Dolphin Emulator on Ubuntu recognize the gamepad?

Comment: It doesn't look so, but I just installed Dolphin and I don't have any .ISO to test

Comment: So if you try to configure a virtual wiimote, it can't pick up your gamepad? (You don't need an ISO to configure gamepads)